# Ubuntu 16.04 can not recognize HDMI-monitor, but Ubuntu 17.10 can

Tags: ubuntu, monitors, hdmi

Currently I am learning how to use Ubuntu, and while I am using Ubuntu 17.10. My HDMI connection to the Acer Monitor works perfectly fine. 
However, Ubuntu 17.10 has some problems about apt-get updates on my machine.

So I have to switch to Ubuntu 16.04. 
Unfortunately, in Ubuntu 16.04, it can not recognize my HDMI-connection to the Monitor.

I don't know why. Although, I tried different solutions already, but It did not change much. 
solution: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/966883/vga-not-listed-in-xrandr-output-projector-not-working-intel-kabylake-graphics/968522#968522

And I hate to admit, but I don't want to mess around with xconfig, that gave me a headache with a log-in loop.

If anyone can help - I really appreciate.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 is like a transition Version, which is very short lived.  18.04 would be a better consideration over 17.10.  You should get at least what you can with 17.10, plus other enhancements and bug fixes.  You'll also get **L**ong **T**erm **S**upport to boot.  Version 16.04 wouldn't be a bad idea, I'm just curious why you are choosing to downgrade over upgrading... especially when you've already had problems with the 16.04 version.

Comment: @L.D.James Sorry, I haven't got back to this forum for awhile. In Ubuntu 17.10, there are some problems about apt-get updates on my machine, and I don't know if It is fixed yet. And fortunately, I fixed the HDMI connection problem by itself.